# Error while executing the oracle query ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I am getting above exception while executing the following query.

```
    SELECT CONSUMER_KEY, AUTHZ_USER,
  ACCESS_TOKEN_TABLE.TENANT_ID, USER_DOMAIN,
  TOKEN_SCOPE, TIME_CREATED,
  REFRESH_TOKEN_TIME_CREATED, VALIDITY_PERIOD,
  REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_PERIOD, USER_TYPE,
  REFRESH_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_TABLE.TOKEN_ID,
  GRANT_TYPE, SUBJECT_IDENTIFIER
FROM
  (SELECT TOKEN_ID, CONSUMER_KEY,
    AUTHZ_USER,IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN.TENANT_ID   AS TENANT_ID,
    IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN.USER_DOMAIN AS USER_DOMAIN,
    TIME_CREATED, REFRESH_TOKEN_TIME_CREATED,
    VALIDITY_PERIOD, REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_PERIOD,
    USER_TYPE,REFRESH_TOKEN,
    IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN.GRANT_TYPE AS GRANT_TYPE,
    SUBJECT_IDENTIFIER
  FROM
    (SELECT *
    FROM IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN
    WHERE ACCESS_TOKEN='xyz'
    AND TOKEN_STATE   ='ACTIVE'
    ) AS IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN
  JOIN IDN_OAUTH_CONSUMER_APPS
  ON CONSUMER_KEY_ID = ID
  ) AS ACCESS_TOKEN_TABLE
LEFT JOIN IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE
ON ACCESS_TOKEN_TABLE.TOKEN_ID = IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE.TOKEN_ID;
```

Appreciate your help to figure out the error on this query.

Exception:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Answer (score 4):

You are aliasing a select result using `AS` keyword, which is giving this error. Just remove `AS` in below two lines and your query will work fine.

```
 - AS IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN
 - AS ACCESS_TOKEN_TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT CONSUMER_KEY, AUTHZ_USER, ACCESS_TOKEN_TABLE.TENANT_ID, USER_DOMAIN, TOKEN_SCOPE, TIME_CREATED, REFRESH_TOKEN_TIME_CREATED, VALIDITY_PERIOD, REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_PERIOD, USER_TYPE, REFRESH_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_TABLE.TOKEN_ID, GRANT_TYPE, SUBJECT_IDENTIFIER FROM (SELECT TOKEN_ID, CONSUMER_KEY, AUTHZ_USER, IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN.TENANT_ID AS TENANT_ID, IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN.USER_DOMAIN AS USER_DOMAIN,TIME_CREATED,REFRESH_TOKEN_TIME_CREATED, VALIDITY_PERIOD, REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_PERIOD, USER_TYPE, REFRESH_TOKEN, IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN.GRANT_TYPE AS GRANT_TYPE,SUBJECT_IDENTIFIER FROM (SELECT * FROM IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN WHERE ACCESS_TOKEN='xyz' AND TOKEN_STATE='ACTIVE') AS IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN JOIN IDN_OAUTH_CONSUMER_APPS as c ON IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN.CONSUMER_KEY_ID = c.ID) AS ACCESS_TOKEN_TABLE LEFT JOIN IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE ON ACCESS_TOKEN_TABLE.TOKEN_ID = IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE.TOKEN_ID;
```

You have given the alias name to the table but not used in the on clause of join.

Answer (score 0):

You have given the 14 columns to be displayed in outer select query:

```
SELECT CONSUMER_KEY,
       AUTHZ_USER,
       ACCESS_TOKEN_TABLE.TENANT_ID,
       USER_DOMAIN,
       TOKEN_SCOPE,
       TIME_CREATED,
       REFRESH_TOKEN_TIME_CREATED,
       VALIDITY_PERIOD,
       REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_PERIOD,
       USER_TYPE,
       REFRESH_TOKEN,
       ACCESS_TOKEN_TABLE.TOKEN_ID,
       GRANT_TYPE,
       SUBJECT_IDENTIFIER
```

and retrieving data from only 13 columns:

```
FROM (SELECT TOKEN_ID,
             CONSUMER_KEY,
             AUTHZ_USER,
             IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN.TENANT_ID AS TENANT_ID,
             IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN.USER_DOMAIN AS USER_DOMAIN,
             TIME_CREATED,
             REFRESH_TOKEN_TIME_CREATED,
             VALIDITY_PERIOD,
             REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_PERIOD,
             USER_TYPE,
             REFRESH_TOKEN,
             IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN.GRANT_TYPE AS GRANT_TYPE,
             SUBJECT_IDENTIFIER
```

and alias to the retrieving data (from ), you have given as to that!

```
AS    IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN
AS ACCESS_TOKEN_TABLE
```

That's all make the changes you are ready to go!